# Why R reads CSV file differently

Tags: r, read.csv

[image: 1]

I am using

```r
myCounts<-read.csv("myCounts.csv", header = TRUE, row.names = 1, sep = ",")
```

and

```r
Book4 <- read_delim("Book4.csv", delim = ";", 
        escape_double = FALSE, trim_ws = TRUE)
```

to read two csv files. But `read.csv` and `read.delim` is pressing them differently.

[image: For myCounts.csv]

[image: For Book4.csv]

Could you please explane how to read in book4 data in the same structure of myCounts data?

Comment: Sorry , Updated it now.

Comment: the question is not very clear, but you can try to import files using fread from data.table: `data.table::fread("Book4.csv")` ...

Comment: Welcome to SO, RitwikMaity! It would be far easier for us to help if we had actual file contents. Can you [edit] your question and post the top (say) 6 lines from each of your files into [code blocks](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (triple `\`\`\`` on their own lines)? With _images_ of data post-read, we can at best speculate what may be wrong. Also ... what is *"pressing them differently"*? The only tangible difference I see is the presence of row names in `myCounts`, the rest looks fine afaict.

Comment: `read.csv()` returns data.frame while `string::read_delim()` treats you with a tibble and there's a difference how rownames are parsed and handled between the 2, you can switch to `read.delim()`  if you prefer to have a data.frame.

Comment: @margusl `read_delim()` is imported from `readr`: https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html

Comment: @GiulioCentorame, indeed. Editing window has closed to fix this but point regarding tibble vs data.frame & difference in rownames remains.

Answer (score 0):

I tried following, it works.

```
df<-read.delim("~/Documents/sample.csv" ,sep  = ";",row.names = 1)
```

Comment: That's `base::read.delim()`, I suspect they're referring to `readr::read_delim()`